# Adding print parent process ID system call to Minix

Tags: c, system, system-calls, minix

This is is the program to Print Process ID and Parent Process ID's in C using Minix. I'm trying to compile the test code below this code to return the ID's but it isn't compiling. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Program to print its Process ID, Parent Process ID 

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "pm.h"  // for various global variables 
  #include "mproc.h"  // for process table mproc

int do_printppids(void)
{

int idx = m_in.m1_i1;
int n = m_in.m1_i2;
while(n > 0 )
{
    int pid = mproc[idx].mp_pid;
    if(pid)
    {
        int parent = mproc[mproc[idx].mp_parent].mp_pid;
        printf("proc: %sn", mproc[idx].mp_name);
        printf("Pid: %d, PPid %dn", pid, parent);
        n++;
    }
    else
    {
        n = 0;
    }
    idx++;
}
return 1;
}
```

This is my test class to try and return the Process ID and Parent Process IDs, but it isn't compiling in Minix.

```
#include <lib.h>    // provides _syscall and message
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // provides atoi

int main(void) {


message m;      // Minix uses message to pass parameters to a system call

m_in.m1_i1 = 0;
m_in.m1_i2 = 10;    

_syscall(PM_PROC_NR, PRINTPPIDS, &m);

}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: test.c:13:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PRINTPPIDS'
    _syscall(PM_PROC_NR, PRINTPPIDS, &m);

Comment: You will have to define `PRINTPPIDS` somewhere which i visible from the `main()` function.

Comment: `PRINTPPIDS` is defined in the `callnr.h` file with the call number 70

Comment: why all that extra effort?   just use: `pid_t parentPid = getppid();` of course the code will need to `#include <sys/types.h>`  and `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: The point is to remake it to understand the inner workings

Answer (score 2):

Literally make sure to update and save all files before running **Make Service + Install** and then recompile the test class. Spent 4 hours staring pointlessly at my code because of it **sigh**